# Is duplication related to answer of a different question valid?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Suppose I want to know the Tithi during Rama's birth and asks a question

> What is the Tithi when Rama takes birth?

If there is another question related to Rama, which is already present in the site with answers

> What is the ritual behind Rama's birth?
>
> (One of the answer) Dasaratha.............Finally, after the ritual, Rama born on **Navami**.

Answer for the first question is present in second question as an answer to it, is it okay to close the first question as duplicate of second question?

The intention of both questions are entirely different, but the answer for one question also answers another question unintentionally.

Comment: IMO, the first question can be answered by citing the second post's answer. They are not duplicates but closely related.

Comment: Not a duplicate..Q can be duplicate of another Q but not of an answer..

Comment: Mr_Green and YDS, please post that as answer.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto not needed, it's a dupe..